# how to create persistent muc room in smack 4.1 beta2

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, smack, multiuserchat

migrated from asmack to smack 4.1 beta2.
The muc rooms created are no longer persistent.

```
MultiUserChatManager mucm=MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
muc=mucm.getMultiUserChat(groupid+"@conference.localhost");
DiscussionHistory histroy=new DiscussionHistory();
histroy.setMaxStanzas(10);
muc.createOrJoin(username,null,histroy,SmackConfiguration.getDefaultPacketReplyTimeout());
muc.nextMessage();
```

when created with gajim, the rooms are persistent.

EDIT : Here is code we used earlier. By default the chat rooms were persistent,

```
muc = new MultiUserChat(connection, groupid+"@conference.localhost");

if(!muc.isJoined())
{
DiscussionHistory histroy=new DiscussionHistory();
histroy.setMaxStanzas(10);
muc.join(username,null,histroy,SmackConfiguration.getDefaultPacketReplyTimeout());
muc.nextMessage(0);
}
```

Comment: How did you previously create persistent rooms? I think you need to send the correct data forum using `MultiUserChat.create` to create a persistent room.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set `muc#roomconfig_persistentroom` to `true` in the MUC configuration from when **creating** the room.

```
MultiuserChat muc = manager.getMultiUserChat("myroom@muc.example.org");
muc.create("myNick");
// room is now created by locked
Form form = muc.getConfigurationForm();
Form answerForm = form.createAnswerForm();
answerForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_persistentroom", true);
muc.sendConfigurationForm(answerForm);
// sending the configuration form unlocks the room
```

Note that not all XMPP MUC services support persistent rooms. For more information see:

- https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/dailybuilds/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/muc/MultiUserChat.html#create(java.lang.String)
- https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/dailybuilds/documentation/extensions/muc.html
- http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#createroom

Comment: I think answerForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_persistentroom", "true"); should be answerForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_persistentroom", true); instead of String a boolean value.

Comment: @flow what should be placed in replacement of "muc#roomconfig_persistentroom"?

Answer (score 5):

You need to submit form like this for making a persistent group:

```java
private void setConfig(MultiUserChat multiUserChat) {
    try {
        Form form = multiUserChat.getConfigurationForm();
        Form submitForm = form.createAnswerForm();
        for (Iterator<FormField> fields = submitForm.getFields(); fields.hasNext();) {
            FormField field = (FormField) fields.next();
            if (!FormField.TYPE_HIDDEN.equals(field.getType()) && field.getVariable() != null) {
                submitForm.setDefaultAnswer(field.getVariable());
            }
        }
        submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_publicroom", true);
        submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_persistentroom", true);
        multiUserChat.sendConfigurationForm(submitForm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In smack 4.1.1, The answers given by @saurabh dixit throw an exception. Please check this thread on ignite website [Correct implementation for persistent rooms smack 4.1.1](https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/55940)

Answer (score 0):

```
        multiUserChatManager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);

        multiUserChat = multiUserChatManager.getMultiUserChat(JidCreate.entityBareFrom(roomJID));

        multiUserChat.create(Resourcepart.from(nickname));

        Form form = multiUserChat.getConfigurationForm();
        Form submitForm = form.createAnswerForm();
        submitForm.getField("muc#roomconfig_enablelogging").addValue("1");
        submitForm.getField("x-muc#roomconfig_reservednick").addValue("0");
        submitForm.getField("x-muc#roomconfig_canchangenick").addValue("0");
        submitForm.getField("x-muc#roomconfig_registration").addValue("0");
        submitForm.getField("muc#roomconfig_passwordprotectedroom").addValue("0");
        submitForm.getField("muc#roomconfig_roomname").addValue(roomName);
        submitForm.getField("muc#roomconfig_whois").addValue("participants");
        submitForm.getField("muc#roomconfig_membersonly").addValue("1");
        submitForm.getField("muc#roomconfig_persistentroom").addValue("1");
        multiUserChat.sendConfigurationForm(submitForm);
```

This is how you can send the room configuration from and configure room.
For more Details please see question.
[How to send room configuration form and create persistce rooms from android using smack 4.3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59540196/how-to-send-room-configuration-form-and-create-persistce-rooms-from-android-usin/59540197#59540197)